# when playing video show pause button in the middle of video jwplayer7

Tags: html, css, video, jwplayer, jwplayer7

I am using jwplayer7, I hide controlbar cause my video is like background video and don't need any controls at the bottom of video, but when playing need to show pause button in the middle of video like play/replay button shows at the beggining/at the end. How can I do this?

Comment: HTML5 or FLASH backend ? and do you have a premium license ?

Comment: yes i have premium license. it is html5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be to create a div and use CSS to position it exactly where you want. Then make sure to call our Javascript API's pause event in the onclick.

It would look something like this:

```
<div style="your_CSS_here" onclick="jwplayer().pause();"></div>
```

By the way, we love Stack Overflow, but we spend more time answering questions submitted directly to our Support page at http://support.jwplayer.com. You might get a faster response from us over there...

Comment: Not sure you're allowed to promote other sites on StackOverflow... although a link to a page containing useful information is good.

Answer (score 2):

Since it's HTML5 you can use simple CSS to hide the controlbar - that way you preserve the rest of the functionality.

I just looked into jwPlayer7 documentation and apparently skinning for JWP7 also uses CSS on flash.

Can't really find the online doc for jw7 skinning on their site -> but what you do is you copy the skin folder you want and use "display:none" on the entire control bar, and load that skin during initialization.

**Edit:**

http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1412123-building-jw-player-skins
http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/2067702-skin-css

Comment: I could hide controllbar, my issue is how to show pause icon during play? @Daniel Batkilin

Comment: JWPlayer has no center pause icon > only a play icon. Where do you want that pause icon to appear ? .. The selector you want appears to be .jw-icon-playback > you can try just applying that through regular CSS even without skinning

Comment: p.s. a hack I can think of is hiding the play icon in the play state, then positioning the pause icon with negative "top:-something px" so that it appears in the center / where you want

Comment: I want it to appear in the middle of video area @Daniel Batkilin

Comment: 1.) Since you use HTML5 you can just use the jwplayer javascript API to create a pause icon yourself, and otherwise hide all the controls or 2.) use absolute positioning for the play/pause icon to place it in the center of the player + hide it when it's in play mode .. it's all regular CSS

Answer (score 2):

The center icon is hidden in the seven skin by default. You can target it and display it when the player is paused like so:

```
.jwplayer.jw-state-paused .jw-display-icon-container {
    display: table;
}
```

This is also the default on mobile browsers and smaller than ~400px setups since jwplayer 7.1. The `.jw-flag-compact-player` CSS class is added to the player container to enable this mode.